# Intel WiFi Adapter not recognized Bionic Beaver

Tags: networking, drivers, 18.04, wireless, iwlwifi

The Wi-Fi adapter in my ASUS Q427F is not recognized by Ubuntu 18.04.3.

I've found literally dozens of similar posts, but none of the steps work for me, hence YAWANFP (yet another wifi adapter not found post). Apologies.

The wireless chip is an Intel WiFi 6 AX201.  This *did* work for me when I first installed Ubuntu (I had to disable secure boot), but on the *very* next update, it stopped working again and is back to being unrecognized.

Secure boot is still disabled.

lshw shows that the hardware is unclaimed:

```
$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Network controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:c441c000-c441ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 1
       logical name: enx00b56d00e75b
       serial: 00:b5:6d:00:e7:5b
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=asix driverversion=22-Dec-2011 duplex=full firmware=ASIX AX88772B USB 2.0 Ethernet ip=192.168.1.37 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
```

Output of lspci:

```
$ lspci -nnk | grep -A2 0280
00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:02f0]
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0074]
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:02e8]
```

There are no system messages related to the iwlwifi driver:

```
$ dmesg | grep iwl
$
```

The device is not disabled in the BIOS:

```
$ rfkill list all
0: hci0: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
1: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
2: asus-bluetooth: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
```

Uninstalling and reinstalling the driver doesn't seem to do anything:

```
$ sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi
$ sudo modprobe iwlwifi
```

Soft-rebooting nor power-off-rebooting does not fix the problem.

Other diagnostics run:

```
$ cat /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[ifupdown]
managed=false

[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

$ cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager

$ iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

enx00b56d00e75b  no wireless extensions.
```

Output from modinfo iwlwifi (truncated):

```
filename:       /lib/modules/5.0.0-36-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko
license:        GPL
author:         Copyright(c) 2003- 2015 Intel Corporation <linuxwifi@intel.com>
description:    Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
firmware:       iwlwifi-100-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-135-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-105-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2030-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2000-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5150-2.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2b-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2a-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6050-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265D-29.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265-17.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-3168-29.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-3160-17.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7260-17.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-8265-36.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-8000C-36.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-9260-th-b0-jf-b0-43.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-9260-th-a0-jf-a0-43.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-9000-pu-a0-jf-b0-43.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-43.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-9000-pu-a0-jf-a0-43.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-Qu-b0-jf-b0-43.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-su-z0-43.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-QuQnj-a0-hr-a0-43.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-QuQnj-a0-jf-b0-43.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-QuQnj-b0-hr-b0-43.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-Qu-b0-hr-b0-43.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-QuQnj-f0-hr-a0-43.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-Qu-a0-jf-b0-43.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-Qu-a0-hr-a0-43.ucode
srcversion:     73136E4A47DE531CDC14864
<<< DJM: all 'alias' lines deleted >>>
depends:        cfg80211
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           iwlwifi
vermagic:       5.0.0-36-generic SMP mod_unload 
signat:         PKCS#7
signer:         
sig_key:        
sig_hashalgo:   md4
parm:           swcrypto:using crypto in software (default 0 [hardware]) (int)
parm:           11n_disable:disable 11n functionality, bitmap: 1: full, 2: disable agg TX, 4: disable agg RX, 8 enable agg TX (uint)
parm:           amsdu_size:amsdu size 0: 12K for multi Rx queue devices, 2K for 22560 devices, 4K for other devices 1:4K 2:8K 3:12K 4: 2K (default 0) (int)
parm:           fw_restart:restart firmware in case of error (default true) (bool)
parm:           antenna_coupling:specify antenna coupling in dB (default: 0 dB) (int)
parm:           nvm_file:NVM file name (charp)
parm:           d0i3_disable:disable d0i3 functionality (default: Y) (bool)
parm:           lar_disable:disable LAR functionality (default: N) (bool)
parm:           uapsd_disable:disable U-APSD functionality bitmap 1: BSS 2: P2P Client (default: 3) (uint)
parm:           enable_ini:Enable debug INI TLV FW debug infrastructure (default: 0 (bool)
parm:           bt_coex_active:enable wifi/bt co-exist (default: enable) (bool)
parm:           led_mode:0=system default, 1=On(RF On)/Off(RF Off), 2=blinking, 3=Off (default: 0) (int)
parm:           power_save:enable WiFi power management (default: disable) (bool)
parm:           power_level:default power save level (range from 1 - 5, default: 1) (int)
parm:           fw_monitor:firmware monitor - to debug FW (default: false - needs lots of memory) (bool)
parm:           d0i3_timeout:Timeout to D0i3 entry when idle (ms) (uint)
parm:           disable_11ac:Disable VHT capabilities (default: false) (bool)
parm:           remove_when_gone:Remove dev from PCIe bus if it is deemed inaccessible (default: false) (bool)
parm:           disable_11ax:Disable HE capabilities (default: false) (bool)
```

Output from uname -a:

```
Linux Bellatrix 5.0.0-36-generic #39~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Nov 12 11:09:50 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I'm at my wit's end, and I despair that the internet is getting tired of answering this question, but I beg your indulgence to try to answer this question at least one more time.

UPDATE: I gave up on 18.04 and installed 19.10, which worked right out of the box.  Backporting probably also would have worked.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Did you install any drivers? It looks like you installed some kernel module without DKMS. After a kernel update it doesn't load.

Comment: Pretty sure I didn’t. I don’t really know what DKMS is.

Comment: It looks like you did because you had to disable Secure Boot. It is needed only if you install a 3rd party module. Maybe you ran some commands that installed it.

Comment: Please add output of `modinfo iwlwifi`

Comment: And also `uname -a`.

Comment: Appreciate the help so far.  I added the modinfo (minus all the alias lines) as well as uname -a.

Comment: When I installed Ubuntu, I did check the option for installing 3rd party software.  I do have a 3rd party NVIDIA driver that shows up under 'additional drivers'.

Comment: Alias lines were also important. Run then `modinfo iwlwifi | grep 02f0`

Comment: None of the alias lines matched "grep 02f0".

Comment: My guess is that because you've got a Intel WiFi 6 AX201, you may need a newer kernel to support it. That, or a new driver backported to 18.04.3. 19.10 might fix it also... try booting to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB 19.10.

Comment: This means that this kernel doesn't support this adapter. You need to find and install backports, or use a newer kernel. It is unlikely it worked before ;-)

Comment: I guess I'll try a newer kernel.  Thanks.  (It certainly did work before, though.)

Comment: Is this Manjaro or stock Ubuntu?

Comment: Here are drivers (microcode) for kernel 5.2... https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/network-and-io/wireless-networking.html

Answer (score 1):

Once I installed 19.10 (over 18.04), it just worked out of the box, so I think the drivers didn't support this newer card.  Don't ask me why it worked briefly.  It's likely that backporting iwlwifi would have worked as well, but I didn't try it.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

Since it worked once, you can try

```
cd backport-iwlwifi
make clean
make
sudo make install
```

Reboot